# React Native onPress alternative

Tags: react-native

I am currently working with this BottomSheet [github page](https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet)

The view is splitted in header and content. The header stays in position, the content is scrollable and also detects if the user wants to close the sheet with sliding down. But now I've got a problem on Android devices. I think the content kind of blocks the onPress so it can detect if the user wants to close it. My TouchableOpacities don't work there. If I press them they fade out (their normal behavior), but onPress isn't triggered. On iOS it works. onPressOut is no alternative for me. Is there a way to get the onPress fired or something like it?

Edit:

Here is my content view:

```
import {Button, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
    __renderExercise = ({item, index}: { item: Exercise, index: number }) => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "auto",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginTop: PADDING
                }}>
                <ImagePlaceholder
                    source={item.image}
                    name={item.name}
                    imageStyle={{
                        width: USER_HEADER_DIMENSION,
                        height: USER_HEADER_DIMENSION,
                        borderRadius: BORDER_RADIUS_SMALL
                    }}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=> /* not called */}
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: PADDING,
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: DEFAULT.primary.colorLight,
                        borderRadius: BORDER_RADIUS_SMALL,
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        padding: PADDING
                    }}>
                    <Text style={{
                        flex: 1
                    }}>{item.name}</Text>
                    <View
                        style={{
                            width: ICON_DIMENSION_SMALL,
                            height: ICON_DIMENSION_SMALL
                        }}>
                        <ArrowForwardSmall color={TEXT_COLOR_LIGHT}/>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    };
```

And the FlatList in the content:

```
<FlatList<Exercise | Recipe>
                style={{
                    height: data.length * (USER_HEADER_DIMENSION + PADDING),
                    width: "100%",
                }}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                bounces={false}
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={((item, index) => item.name + index)}
                renderItem={this.__renderExercise}
            />
```

BottomSheet: if I use the component in renderHeader it works, but in content not.

```
<BottomSheet
            enabledInnerScrolling={false}
            snapPoints={[PlanScreenBottomSheetMinHeight, PlanScreenBottomSheetMaxHeight]}
            renderContent={() => RenderContent(day, isWorkoutDay)}
            renderHeader={() => RenderHeader(day, isWorkoutDay)}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show a sample of your code or the specific file you have this error.

Then another thing, make sure you are importing TouchableOpacity from react native like this:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

and not from react-native-gesture-handler -

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Comment: sure. But I use the TouchableOpacity from react, not gesture handler